# MongoDB Data modeling, Document embedding and document reference

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB. I want to design a post structure with some comments and each comment has a username and avatar, but I don't know which relationship to use for, embedding comments inside post and user inside comment or user reference?

**Update**
If embedding document is the selected option, what about updating the original user avatar, How it should be propagated to embedded documents?
Also if I have a country for user with multilingual names what's the best option to reference country inside user?

Answer (score 0):

- If you can tolerate data being inconsistent for a short period of
  time, use Embedding.
- If you can tolerate slower queries, use Referencing

## Referencing a document

```
const Users = mongoose.Schema({
  username : String,
  avatar : String,
});

const Comments =  mongoose.Schema({
  title : String,
  user : { type: new mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: Users }
});

const Posts = new mongoose.Schema({
  comments : [{ type: new mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: Comments }]
})
```

- If you want data consistency, you can choose Referencing documents.
- Here the representation of the document is in a single place.
- You will need to lookup other collections or send multiple queries to get the complete representation of the document.
- This will impact the performance of your queries

## Embedding a document

```
const Comments =  new mongoose.Schema({
  title : String,
  user : Users
});

const Users = new mongoose.Schema({
  username : String,
  avatar : String,
});

const Posts = new mongoose.Schema({
  comments : [Comments]
})
```

- If you want query performance, you can choose Embedding documents.
- We can read a complete representation of a document with a single
  query.
- We will have multiple copies of a document in different places.
- Having multiple copies means changes made to the original document may not propagate to all copies.
- If the database server crash during an update, some documents will be
  inconsistent.
- Embedded documents don’t have a save method. They can only be saved in the context of their parent